# where can i get libstdc++5 packages

Tags: 12.04, libraries

Does any body know where can i get the below packages:

`libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
`libstdc++5_3.3.6-17ubuntu1_i386.deb`

I was following this [link](http://www.digitalenigma.net/directory.php?include=archives&msgid=2009111000) and the location referenced in that tutorial does not exist any more..

Thanks so much..

Comment: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/

Comment: @ZhangYuan  I searched for both the packages there and it returns nothing

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 12.04, you should be able to just run

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libstdc++5 libstdc++5:i386
```

Comment: This helped me run XARA Linux, on Ubuntu 14.04 X64.

Comment: Helped me on Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Answer (score 2):

You need to add i386 architecture first and then install libstdc++5

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
```

[Source](http://myquerysolution.blogspot.in/2018/01/installing-libstdc5-on-ubuntu-64-bit.html)

Comment: This answer saved my day. In my case, I was struggling to install the CheckPoint's SNX (SSL Network Extender) VPN client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one I have found http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libstdc++5, hope it helps.